# does "artsy" have negative connotations?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

The dictionaries seem to indicate so, but its not clear how the word is really used. 
Also, is the word about person's art abilities, or taste in art?
Edit: Is it an internet slang, or general English slang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word does have some pejorative cast to it.  It is not internet slang; it predates the widespread adoption of the internet (I remember it from ~1980s).

The word exists in **contrast to** the word "artistic".  It often means, when applied to a person, that they have the personal **style** associated with artists: it suggests that they present themselves -- in speech, dress, habit, activity -- as belonging to a subculture of artists.  In an important sense, it functions like calling someone a goth or punk rock or emo: you're saying something of how they seem to you, in terms of subcultural style affiliation.

Perhaps a better definition is that *artsy* means *in the style of artists*, where it is understood that there is some artists' style being alluded to.  It is in the very differentiation between actually *being* an artist, and (merely) adopting the *style* of artists, that the pejorative implication arises.

Comment: I think it's more like calling someone a poser, hodad, wannabe or dilettante. An outsider pretending to be an insider. Incidentally, I don't perceive "artsy-craftsy" as pejorative; it just describes someone who can make cute stuff. Not great art, but decorative.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I disagree that that's essential to the term.  While it can be used to call someone a poser, I have the impression I've heard it used to disparage someone for their subcultural affiliation as artists, with no comment on their authenticity as artists at all.  I'm just reminded of a friend's blog which has "Artsy" in the title, referring to her.  In context -- she's a classical musician, the blog is about her professional music making -- she's being self-deprecating in using it, alluding playfully to the fact that yes, her music is what some might term "artsy-fartsy".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock (I'd never heard the term hodad before.  Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a common English slang term and could be mildly pejorative. See [here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/artsy), where it is described as "enthusiastic about [art], though it may also describe someone who is pretentious".